# Excel 2003 Alphabetic Sort Order Is Not My Idea of Alphabetic

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003, sorting

I have an Excel 2003 spreadsheet that I'm sorting on the first column, which is formatted as Text. The sort order is strange. Here's a "sorted" example. I've highlighted the anomaly.

120-BDXX

120G-EDXX

120G-MEXX

120G-PRXX

**120-SSXX**  <==== Why is 120-S *after* 120G-PR?

120T-03XX

Am I missing something or does Excel define alphabetical order differently than most people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It ignores the dashes.

Comment: Thanks -- found http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/sorting.htm which states the same thing. I guess there may be situations where you want this to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should create separate columns on which to sort and then sort on multiple columns.
1. the column that has "120" etc.
2. the column that has or has not "G" etc.
3. the column that has "BDXX" etc
This would also make things like filtering, pivot tables, viable.
I would do that. Either manually or by a VBA macro using regexp.
Hope that helps you arrive at a useful and flexible solution. Don't get into a trap of working with convoluted data packed into one string.